# Query in a string column for one of the value in an array like multiple OR (using full text search)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a rails 4 app, in one model I have a column containing multiple ids as a string with comma separated values.

```
"123,4568,12"
```

I have a "search" engine that I use to retrieve the records with one or many values using the full text search of postgresql I can do something like this which is very useful:

```
records = MyModel.where("my_models.col_name @@ ?", ["12","234"])
```

This return all the records that have both 12 and 234 in the targeted column. The array comes from a form with a multiple select.

Now I'm trying to make a query that will find all the records that have either 12 or 234 in there string.

I was hopping to be able to do something like:

```
records = MyModel.where("my_models.col_name IN (?)", ["12","234"])
```

But it's not working.

Should I iterate through all the values in the array to build a query with multiple OR ?  Is there something more appropriate to do this?

**EDIT / TL;DR**

@BoraMa answer is a good way to achieve this.

To find all the records containing one or more ids referenced in the request use:

```
records = MyModel.where("my_models.col_name @@ to_tsquery(?)", ["12","234"].join('|'))
```

You need the to_tsquery(?) and the join with a single pipe `|`to do a `OR` like query.

To find all the records containing exactly all the ids in the query use:

```
records = MyModel.where("my_models.col_name @@ ?", ["12","234"])
```

And of course replace ["12","234"] with something like `params[:params_from_my_form]`

[Postgres documentation for full text search](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch.html)

Comment: Can you change the schema so that you're not storing CSV in a column? Maybe use a PostgreSQL array column instead.

Comment: I just see your comment. Actually I can't change the schema but's that's a good idea for the future. For the moment I'll continue using the advantage of full text search. See my update for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already started to use the fulltext search in Postgres in the first place,I'd try to leverage it again. I think you can use a **fulltext `OR` query** which can be constructed like this:

```
records = MyModel.where("my_models.col_name @@ to_tsquery(?)", ["12","234"].join(" | "));
```

This uses the `|` operator for `OR`ing fulltext queries in Postgres. I have not tested this and maybe you'll need to do `to_tsvector('my_models.col_name')` for this to work.

See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH) for more info.

Comment: Hi BoraMa, your approach seems very promising I think this could actually works. Let me try your idea and I get back to you! Thanks.

Comment: It's working, you lead me on the right path. the tricky thing is that the `OR` operator for full text is a single `|` their documentation where not totally clear for my purpose. The to_tsquery is necessary but not the tsvector that is seems to be for grouping col you want to search in. I'll update my question to provide informations for future readers. I suggest you update your answer too. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: Great that you got it working! I updated the answer based on you findings.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely useful and now I can set search engine for exclusive or inclusive match.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your ids are :

a="1,2,3,4"

You can simply use:

```
ModelName.find(a)
```

This will give you all the record of that model whose id is present in a.

Comment: Hi kajal, I think your missing the point. I'm no trying to find the model which ids are referenced in the query. I'm trying to find the model which holds the references of another one (ex: categories ids). Sadly a simple find cannot work in this case. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

I just think a super simple solution, we just sort the ids in saving callback of `MyModel`, then the query must be easier:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :sort_ids_in_col_name, if: :col_name_changed?

  private

  def sort_ids_in_col_name
    self.col_name = self.col_name.to_s.split(',').sort.join(',')
  end
end
```

Then the query will be easy:

```
ids = ["12","234"]
records = MyModel.where(col_name: ids.sort.join(',')
```

Comment: Hi Hieu, thanks for your answer but a `where(col_name: ids)` will be an exact match an I will not be able to find the records that have, for instance, only one of the ids from the query. And to find the records that have all the ids the `@@` search is perfect because it's looking for each words (or id in my case) that are separated by a comma. Imagine that I'm trying to find a simple query to avoid to generate a long one with a lot of `OR` in it (one `OR`for each id).